# undefined is not an object (evaluating props)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

buenas, disculpen, alguien ha utilizado expo-background-Fetch y expo-Task-Manager?

mi duda es si puedo llamar a un metodo de una clase en el mismo archivo e la clase, pero afuera claro, ese metodo usa props para hacer su funcion, lo intente hacer, pero me ocasiona un error... el error que me ocasiona es: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.setForceUpdate')]

como pueden ver es un props, y no solamente ese props, si no todos los props que utilizo en ese metodo... he investigado y encontre que un posible error que tenga es el alcance...

Se preguntaran porque quiero llamar el metodo en el mismo archivo js, ahh pues porque quiero registrar una tarea en segundo plano, y para registrar una tarea en segundo plano debo de utilizar TaskManager.defineTask() y ese metodo no puede ser definido dentro de un componente, y la clase es extendido de un componente, por eso lo declaro en el mismo archivo pero afuera de la clase...

estoy utilizando react y expo..  este es el codigo...

```js
    async uploadAndUpdate() {
        const { setForceUpdate } = this.props;
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const updatedHistory = await this.gembaUtilities.getUpdatedHistory(params.historyId);
        this.registerBackgroundFetchAsync();

        const { evidencesToUpload } = this.state;
        if (evidencesToUpload.length == 0) {

            //SI no hay evidencias  entra aqui
            this.unregisterBackgroundFetchAsync();

            console.log("evidencias locales => ", evidenciasLocales);

            evidenciasLocales.forEach(async (evidence, index) => {
                await this.apiFetcher.insertEvidence(
                    this.state.reportId, evidence.locationId, evidence.taskId, evidenceUpload[index]);
            });

            evidenciasLocales = [];
            setForceUpdate(true);
            try {
                await this.apiFetcher.sendAutomaticReport({ 'historyId': params.historyId });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error => ', error);
            }
            await this.appStorage.delete('histories', params.historyId);
            return this.props.navigation.navigate('PrincipalScreen');
        }

        const firstEvidence = evidencesToUpload[0];
        evidenciasLocales.push(firstEvidence);
        evidencesSigned.push(arrayUrlFirmadas[contador].url)

        console.log("evidencias para subir ??>> ", evidencesSigned[contador])
        const url = evidencesSigned[contador].split('?');
        evidenceUpload.push(url[0]);
        console.log("URL SIN ? ", evidenceUpload)

        console.log(`Parametros para _saveToSignedUrl ${evidencesSigned[contador]}  || ${firstEvidence.data}`)
        let resul = await this.S3Uploader._saveToSignedUrl(evidencesSigned[contador], firstEvidence.data);
        console.log("respuesta de upload =>> ", resul)

        //Eliminar la evidencia que ya se subio
        newEvidences = [...evidencesToUpload];
        newEvidences.shift();
        console.log('New evidences => ', newEvidences);

        updatedHistory.evidencesToUpload = newEvidences;
        //await this.appStorage.update('histories', updatedHistory);

        contador++;

        this.setState({ evidencesToUpload: newEvidences });
        setTimeout(async () => {
            await this.uploadAndUpdate();
        }, 100);
    }
```

```js
TaskManager.defineTask(TASK, async () => {
    const screenList = new ListUploadScreen()
  await screenList.uploadAndUpdate();
  console.log(" --------------------------- ");
  return BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData;
});
```

el TaskManager.defineTask esta afuera de la clase

Comment: Desconozco _react_, pero algo me dice que `uploadAndUpdate` debería ser un [componente](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) (o algo similar) para poder acceder a `.props`.

Comment: es un metodo de un componente,  o sea, un metodo que esta dentro de una clase que extiende de un componente por ejemplo

class ListUploadScreen extends Component {
 //cuerpo del componente 

//metodo uploadAndUpdate
async uploadAndUpdate() {

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Tratándose de un método, seguramente se está generando un nuevo contexto, por lo que debes enlazar el valor que quieras usar para `this`:

### Opción 1: Enlazar con [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

En el constructor de la clase enlazas el valor adecuado para `this`

```
constructor(props) {
    // Siempre se debe ejecutar super() cuando se extiende una clase
    super(props);
    // Asignar el contexto de la clase al método
    this.uploadAndUpdate.bind(this);
}
```

### Opción 2: Convertir método en [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

Las funciones flecha no generan un contexto propio, sino que toman el mismo que se crea donde son definidas, en este caso, la clase.

```
uploadAndUpdate = async () => {
    // Aquí el resto de tu código
}
```